# Knockout custom binding fires multiple times

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm currently trying to create a custom binding for my webpage, where I have a visible span and hidden input element. If I'm to click on the span, it will disappear and the input will appear. Once the input loses focus, the span is updated with the new value from the input. However, for some reason my `blur` function is being binded again each time I click my span, which is not what I want. How can I fix this?

HTML

```
<!-- ko foreach: formula -->
  <span data-bind="text: $data, attr: {name: $index}, convert: $index()"></span>
  <input data-bind="value: $data, attr: {name: $index}" class="hide"/><br/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JavaScript

```
ko.bindingHandlers.convert = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).click(function() {
      var index = valueAccessor();
      var inputName = "input[name="+index+"]";
      $(element).addClass("hide");
      $(inputName).removeClass("hide").focus().blur(function() {
        console.log("firing");
        $(inputName).addClass("hide");
        $(element).removeClass("hide");
        $(element).text($(inputName).val());
      });
    });
  }
};
```

So if I click on my span twice, I would get

```
firing
firing
firing
```

in my console when I'm only supposed to get `firing` twice.

Note: I can't follow the `hasFocus` example from the Knockout tutorial as it binds to all input fields, and I need my input fields to toggle only for that specific span that is being clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a mystery at all. Look at that code:

```
$(element).click(function() {
    /* some code */
    $(inputName).blur(function() {
        /* some code */
    });
});
```

Each time you click you add `blur` handler. You may try removing handlers like this:

```
$(element).click(function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var index = valueAccessor();
    var inputName = "input[name="+index+"]";
    var $input = $(inputName);
    $element.addClass("hide");
    $input.unbind('blur');
    $inputName.removeClass("hide").focus().blur(function() {
        console.log("firing");
        $input.addClass("hide");
        $element.removeClass("hide");
        $element.text($input.val());
    });
});
```

I think you can chain it, didn't test it though.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple! Thanks! I didn't need the second unbind function though. `$(inputName).unbind('blur');` was sufficient to make the code work.

Comment: @WeiHao Of course. I left second `unbind` by mistake. I've edit the code. :) By the way: I've refactored your code a bit, I've cached some variables to make it more efficient.